# Naming Convention: Non-Generic

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

If the following is a generic object:

```
public class Kennel<T>
{
    public List<T> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

This would be a non-generic object:\

```
public class Kennel
{
    public List<Dog> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a good term for a non-generic class (aside from non-generic)?

Comment: Standard or maybe concrete?

Comment: Yea - concrete is pretty good but I already use it to describe non-abstract classes...which is another way of categorizing classes... maybe if I could think of a better description of a non-abstract class?

Answer (score 4):

There is no good term defined for what you want in the C# specification.  The specification defines:

- An open type involves a type parameter; all non-open types are closed types.  So all non-generic types are closed types, but so is `List<int>`.  No type parameter in there; `int` is a type *argument*.  `List<T>` is an open type.
- An unbound type is either a non-generic type or the type of a declaration of a generic type. Like if you say `class C<T>` then the abstract notion of "`C`-of-one-type-parameter" is an unbound type, and `C<int>` is a bound type. Non-generic types are both bound and unbound, so that doesn't help you either. Note that in `class C<T> { public static C<T> c; }` the second `C<T>` is a bound type; the type parameter has been supplied and it is `T`.

The C# specification just uses "non-generic" whenever that is meant.